# Upload audio file to soundcloud using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, soundcloud

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string postData = "client_id=" + "b408123adf1e3a950876d84475587ca2"
                  + "&client_secret=" + "d74a342169f5f5b369622d582f77b09e"
                  + "&grant_type=password&username=" + "biksad" //your username
                  + "&password=" + "369789";//your password :)
string soundCloudTokenRes = "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";
string tokenInfo = client.UploadString(soundCloudTokenRes, postData);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://soundcloud.com/biksad/tracks") as HttpWebRequest;

//some default headers
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");

//file array
var files = new UploadFile[] { new UploadFile(filePath, "@" + fileName, "application/octet-stream") };

//other form data
var form = new NameValueCollection();
form.Add("track[title]", "biksad");
form.Add("track[sharing]", "public");
form.Add("oauth_token", tokenInfo);
form.Add("format", "json");
form.Add("Filename", fileName);
form.Add("Upload", "Submit Query");
string lblInfo;

try
{
    using (var response = HttpUploadHelper.Upload(request, files, form))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            lblInfo = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblInfo = ex.ToString();
}
```

I want to upload an audio file from my server to my soundcloud account. I got this error:

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

How can I detect "form" values correctly(track[title],track[sharing]...etc.)?

Comment: i hope they are not your actual keys and passwords...

Comment: Nı. Thy are not my actual keys

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with? Uploading the files, or reading form values?

Answer (score 0):

this link will show you what all the fields on that POST mean
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

you can also use this tool they provide to look at what the URL should contain:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/console